# Object type for compiled module

Tags: pydev

I am working with compiled modules *.pyd. I have to inform python what type is an object I am using. I am working with pydev (https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html). To have properly working auocomplete, for each variable\obj I have to put the type like that:

```
import compiled_module
some_obj = compiled_module.SomeClass.GetObject() #: :type some_obj : compiled_module.ObjectClass
```

I wonder if there an option in the pydev to put the information about the type automaticly `#: :type some_obj : compiled_module.ObjectClass` 
During typing name of class\method pydev generate information about `:rtype: :py:class: compiled_module.ObjectClass`

[image: pydev information about object]

Comment: Make your question clear

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's no such option in PyDev at this point (the idea seems interesting thought, so, feel free to create a ticket in the PyDev tracker: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/ -- although I don't have any time frame to give on when this'd be available).